# Java ScrollPane Implementation for canvas

Tags: java, canvas, viewport

This is a bit of an abstract question if you will, in that i dont actually have any code to show you. Im wondering if any of you can give me some advise on how i would do the following. I beleieve the appropriate thing to use is a viewport or scrollpane but correct me if im wrong

ok so im making a RTS game in java as a pet project. in this game is a jframe that contains a class which extends canvas -and is a canvas for all intents and purposes.it is on that canvas that game objects are displayed/ controled/ etc. my problem is that the game field (canvas) can only be as big as the window. i want the player to be able to control where the camera is so that they can pan around the canvas by putting the mouse near the end of the window. (ie move mouse to right most side of window and to pan the "camera" to the right). i think i should use a viewport to scroll across the canvas but i have never used one before so i was wondering if any of you could give me some pointers

Comment: I don't think you should be thinking about moving/scrolling a "camera" since as I understand it is a 2D game, you should be thinking about moving all the canvas content, all drawings based on mouse position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up using a java.awt.ScrollPane and put my canvas inside of it